# Hibernate @Formula / ERROR: schema "FOO" does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm updating old libraries from a legacy system. Just now i'm trying to update Hibernate 3.4.0.GA to 4.3.11.Final, i just needed to change small things in the code, everything was fine. But when i put the system to run, i'm receiving a **"schema "FOO" does not exist"** while execute a query. Trying to isolate the problem, i discovered this happen from Hibernate 3.5.1 to 3.5.2 and the reasons.

Hibernate when generating the sql, is adding schema to functions. I show now the difference in two versions.

**protocolo_1** is the alias of main schema, this is a subquery added by @Formula in Protocolo.java, the name of schema is protocolo too.

**@Formula**

`select max (pm2.id) from protocolo.protocolomovimento pm2 where pm2.id_protocolo = id`

**Hibernate 3.5.1 SQL generated**

`select max (pm2.id) from protocolo.protocolomovimento pm2 where pm2.id_protocolo = protocolo1_.id`

**Hibernate 3.5.2 SQL generated**

`select protocolo_1.max (pm2.id) from protocolo.protocolomovimento pm2 where pm2.id_protocolo = protocolo1_.id`

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.12 with respective driver and org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect (in this versions of hibernate, it's the unique dialect to PostgreSQL)

I found another guy with similar problem here [Why is Hibernate adding schema name to Hsql functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37580077/why-is-hibernate-adding-schema-name-to-hsql-functions) but i think its only similar, it's not my case.

Why is Hibernate doing this? How can i fix this?

Comment: Is there a space character after max? Try to remove it

Comment: thank you @Konstantin V. Salikhov . I removed the space and worked, i didnt  see that space. Please write the answer so can i accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like hibernate don't understand space character between `max` and `(` in expression `max (pm2.id)`, so it thinks that max is column name and adds table alias there.

Removing space will solve the problem.